# why are my r markdown inline codes not evaluated

Tags: r, markdown

I got this peculiar problem of inline code in r markdown not evaluated, even for the simplest possible codes. for example 2+2 = 'r 2+2'.   Or 2+2= 'r x'. Where the value of x is defined in an r code chunk in advance.  In both situations, the inline codes will be print as-is when knitting instead of evaluated to show their values. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're using backticks (`) and not apostrophes (').

Reference:

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html